# How to calculate covariance matrix weighted by elements, not by rows or columns?

Tags: pca, covariance, covariance-matrix, weighted-data

**I want to calculate *weighted covariance matrix* where the weights are given to each element** (entry, cell) of the original data matix, and not to rows (as done by [cov.wt](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cov.wt.html) in `stats`).

The issue had been discussed on CrossValidated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113485/weighted-principal-components-analysis), but no actual implementation (e.g. in a form of R code) was presented. Some solutions are offered by [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0502056v1.pdf) and [this](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~zamir/documents/lower.pdf) papers, but are impenetrable to me and I lack the skill to code them.

Is there a package or a function that does it? Or, would anybody be able to come up with a couple of lines of code that can do it?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to do PCA with weights or do you really need to compute covariance matrix? The algorithm of Gabriel & Zamir directly finds a low-rank approximation to $X$ given weights $W$; it's not computing a "weighted covariance matrix". I am not sure what it even means to compute covariance matrix with weights.

Comment: Ultimately, yes, I'd like to compute PCA with weights, and for that I need a weighted covariance matrix. But as I said, I need to weight each observation in the original dataset -- I have a measure of error associated with each data point, which I want to put into the analysis as a weight. My intuition tells me that if I can weight rows in the original dataset using `cov.wt`, I should also be able to weight the individual data entries. But I struggle to actually do this weighting. And the math in the papers that describe it is impenetrable.

Comment: Yes, I understand that your weights are cell-specific. My point is that to do a "weighted PCA" (as described in Gabriel & Zamir or in a similar way) you do **not** need to compute a "weighted covariance matrix" first. As I said, I am not even sure how to define a "weighted covariance matrix". That's why I am trying to clarify if your question is actually primarily about weighted PCA (and whether one needs a cov matrix for that or not is secondary), or if it is primarily about weighted cov matrix (and whether to do PCA with it or not is secondary).