# PCA with non-Euclidean norm?

Tags: pca, weights

I have a dataset $X$ which I want to perform PCA on- however, I don't care so much about explaining the variance of certain features. So instead of using the "normal" definition of reconstruction loss:
$$L(w)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}||x-(x\cdot{}w)w||^{2}$$
I want to use a modified norm:
$$L_{A}(w)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}||x-(x\cdot{}w)w||_{A}^{2}$$
where for some $v$,
$$||v||_{A}=v^{T}Av$$
with $A$ a diagonal matrix whose elements can be thought of as feature "weights". So the new PCA problem is:
$$\min_{w}L_{A}(w)$$
Is there a closed-form solution to this, in the same way that one can derive that the solution to standard PCA is the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix $X^{T}X$?

Comment: There is already a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113485/weighted-principal-components-analysis) posted.

Comment: This is identical to usual PCA.  It is solved using so-called "generalized eigenvalues," but geometrically the $A$ norm is a Euclidean norm, so it introduces no conceptual or even computational difficulties.  But there's an apparent inconsistency: when $A$ is your norm, it doesn't make much sense to subtract a projected value based on the *different* Euclidean norm.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you elaborate on how you would use generalized eigenvalues to solve this?

Comment: I had noticed the inconsistency that you mentioned, but I don't think it's an issue. Conceptually, I still want to see how far x is from its normal projection - I just want to measure this distance differently.

Comment: I also recommend having a look at the mixed PCA, implemented in the R package `PCAmixdata`. In their paper two weight matrices are used to measure distances differently for categorical and continuous features.  The pre-print of the paper is called: Chavent, M., Kuentz-Simonet, V., Labenne, A., Saracco, J., Multivariate analysis of mixed data: The PCAmixdata R package.